# Python - New line being ignored during input

Tags: python, binary, newline

I have a program that outputs the binary of an inputted string:

```
b = [format(ord(c), 'b') for c in m]
print(b)
```

This prints everything fine, except when I put in characters like a new line, it ignores the ascii values of those. For example:

```
>>>'hello[insert new line] qwertyuiop'
>>>['1101000', '1100101', '1101100', '1101100', '1101111']
```

In fact, the program ignores everything after the new line. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did whatever you are doing and added a `\n` character in the middle, and got `['1101000', '1100101', '1101100', '1101100', '1101111', '1010', '100000', '1110001', '1110111', '1100101', '1110010', '1110100', '1111001', '1110101', '1101001', '1101111', '1110000']` as th output

Comment: Try `'hello\n qwertyuiop'` to insert a newline or use `'''` quotes around the whole string doing it your way.

Comment: @Barghav Rao That's because it counts the `\ ` and `n` as separate characters and gets their individual ascii values. If you type a new line elsewhere, then copy-paste it in, you get the results I got.

Comment: _"when I put in characters like a new line"_ - it all depends on how you do that.... but you don't show us working code. How did you input the data? Did that method split on newlines? `m = 'hello\n qwertyuiop'` works fine.